# What should I do to prevent a 401 Unauthorised when using the Swagger Type Provider?

Tags: f#, swagger, type-providers

When attempting to perform an HTTP post via [Swagger](https://github.com/fsprojects/SwaggerProvider) (using the Swagger Type Provider) I get a 401 Unauthorized.

I suspect the answer to this might be UseDefaultCredentials which isn't exposed when inheriting from the [SwaggerProvider.Internal.ProvidedSwaggerBaseType](https://github.com/fsprojects/SwaggerProvider/blob/master/src/SwaggerProvider.Runtime/RuntimeHelpers.fs). So I was thinking that an upcast :> might help but posts I've seen elsewhere indicate naïveté.

Also, updating the config for fsi.exe to include the following proved wishful:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
    <proxy usesystemdefault="True" />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Might anyone have a *simple* answer?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Schema access

`SwaggerProvider` assumes that Swagger schema is easy-accessible and can be downloaded using simple Http request without authentication

```
type PetStore = SwaggerProvider<"http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json">
```

user also can add any HTTP header to schema-request like this

```
type PetStore = SwaggerProvider<"http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json", "Content-Type=application/json">
```

It can be `Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1l` header, but this literal string will be hard-coded in source code.

If schema-request requires more complex authentication, will be easier to download it and put it near source code

```
[<Literal>]
let schemaPath = __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__ + "/PetStore.Swagger.json"
type PetStore = SwaggerProvider<schemaPath>
```

### Requests control

When schema are in place you have a full control over all HTTP request to the server using `CustomizeHttpRequest` parameter in provided type.

For example, if you want to use default credentials:

```
let store = 
  PetStore(
    CustomizeHttpRequest=
      fun (req:System.Net.HttpWebRequest) ->
        req.UseDefaultCredentials <- true
        req)
```

You are free to modify web request as you need:

- Use default credentials
- Specify runtime Credentials
- Add headers to HTTP request
- Add cookies to HTTP request
- Break request ;) and etc.

`CustomizeHttpRequest` will be called in the run-time for each request, after `SwaggerProvider` built it and before call to the server. So you can change anything you want.